# How could I iterate through the elements of a list to make API calls for a number of zip codes?

Tags: python, pandas, google-api, jupyter-notebook

I am locating coordinates (latitude and longitude) for thirty different zip codes.  I am able, with the code that I have utilized, to find results for one particular zip code, but have not been able to determine how to iterate through the elements of the list that I had created earlier in my notebook.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
from pprint import pprint

from api_file import api_key

zip_code_data_file = "../ZipCodes.csv"
zip_code_df = pd.read_csv(zip_code_data_file)
zipcodes = []
for zipcode in zip_code_df['Zip Codes']:
    zipcodes.append(zipcode)
url = ("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&components=country:US|postal_code:[63xxx]&key={}").format(api_key)
geo_data = requests.get(url).json()
```

I am able to return results for the particular zip code that I enter, but I cannot determine how to create the url variable in order iterate through the list and to return results for all of the elements of the list.

Comment: Isn't a string replacement enough?

Comment: Could you paste a sample input and output ?

Comment: The `url=... and line after that should inside the loop` and append the result.